# About React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to get data from a socket service than I want to keep it with redux.

No changes in components, just get data and write it realt-time.

But i cant do it, how can i do it ?  please help me.

Index.js

```
    // React 
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
    // Redux *********************************
    import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
    import { store } from './Redux/store';
```

Redux Store.js

```
    import { createStore } from 'redux';
    import { rootReducer } from './rootReducer';

    export const store = createStore(
    rootReducer
    );
```

rootDeducer.js

```
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import { someReducer } from './reducers/someReducer';

    const allReducers = {
      someReducer
    };

    export const rootReducer = combineReducers(allReducers);
```

someReducer.js

```
     const initialState = {
     someValue: 12
     };

     export const someReducer= function(state = initialState, action) {
     switch (action.type) {
        case 'CHANGE':
         const someVlue= Object.assign({}, state, { someValue: 
         action.payload.someVlue});
         return someValue;

       default:
         return state;
      }
     };
```

Comment: Can you clarify, what exactly is wrong with the current code (error message, doesn't work as expected etc.)?

Comment: @SergeiPetunin Actually, there's nothing wrong with the code. but he can't determine my need. For example, in my home componentim I can show someValue. and how to keep continuous websocket data stored.

Comment: I can't say anything about storing the websocket data in your application, since there's nothing related to websockets in your code, it's mostly just boilerplate. If you currently have nothing and just need to jumpstart your react/websocket application, I'm sure there's plenty of tutorials around the web.

Answer (score 0):

You can dispatch action on every update from websocket e.g.

```
// assuming this function executes on websocket update
update =(data) => { 
  store.dispatch(someAction(data))
}
// or if you are mapping action using redux connect HOC.
update = (data) => {
  this.props.someAction(data);
}
```